# How to give an array of templates as a parameter in a function?

Tags: c++

I was studying for my C++ exam and noticed that my answer differs from the solution. The question was to write a method that gives the biggest double or string (by size) from an array with templates. I know that by passing the array as a parameter you give a pointer to the first index. 
I'm really confused on where I should write the "const" to signify that the array is not being altered though.    Also the code contains 2 dutch words, "*grootste*" means "*biggest*", and "*grootte*" just means *"size"*. PS: *max= maximum*

this is my **solution**:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

template <typename T>
T grootste(T const [],int);
double grootte(double);

int grootte(const string&);


int main(){
    double getallen[5] = {5.5,7.7,2.2,9.8,9.9};
    string woorden[3] = {"geloof","hoop","de liefde"};

    cout << "Biggest number " << grootste(getallen,5) << "." << endl;
    cout << "Longest of 3 strings " << grootste(woorden,3) << "." << 
    endl;
    return 0;
    }

int grootte(const string &a){
    return a.size();
}
double grootte(double d){
    return d;
}

template <typename T>
T grootste (T const arr[], int lengte){
    T max=arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<lengte;i++){
        if(grootte(arr[i])>grootte(max)){
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

this is the solution my course gives me, there was no main included and the other methods were the same. 
I wrote the solution again but now it's a literal copy from the pdf the students recieved. I'm sorry for the spacing, i have no idea why it does that.

```
template < class T >
T grootste ( const T * array , int lengte ){
    T gr = array [0];
    for ( int i =1; i < lengte ; i ++) {
        if ( grootte ( gr ) < grootte ( array [i ]) ){
            gr = array [i ];
        }
    }
return gr ;
}
```

Comment: `const T * arr[]` is an array of pointers. That doesn't look right; most likely, either the star `*` or a pair of square brackets `[]` is a typo. It doesn't make sense to have both here. `const T* arr` and `const T arr[]` are equivalent and mean the same thing - an array of `T`s

Comment: The second version wants an array of pointers to `T`, and can't really compile, since `arr[0]` will have the type of `T*`, and value of `T` can't be assigned to the value of `T*` (except in some bizarre custom-tailored cases)

Comment: I'm sorry I should have added a direct copy from the pdf we recieved, apparently i typed over some errors. Now it's staight from the professor so the solution is now 100% correct. (The second part that is)

Comment: Unrelated, the temp `gr` is avoidable in the professor's "100% correct" code. Don't make a temp; keep the *index* to the greater element instead, `gidx` initially at `0`, and changed when appropriate. Then return `array[gidx]` as the final result. This avoids unnecessary copy-assignment and copy-ctor. Alternatively, use pointers instead, or better still, a version that uses iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parameters are all equivalent:

```
const T p[]
T const p[]
const T *p
T const *p
```

Which one to choose is a matter of taste and convention.

Comment: So is my solution is equally correct as the given solution? I know there's some instances where if you don't use the  right convention points are subtracted from your exam answer. For instance determineBiggest() in Java  en determine_biggest() in cpp. Thanks a lot for answering my question.

Comment: @ZwarteKop Conventions and scoring is a matter for you and your teachers. In general, if there's a specific spelling in the exam, you should write exactly that and not something equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I always get confused when types get complex. Use a `typedef`/`using` statement to make it clear what you mean exactly.

```
using intptr = int*; //pointer to int

void foo(const intptr arr ) {  // a const pointer to int
    arr[0] = 32;
    // arr = nullptr; //This will fail
}

using cint = const int; 

void bar(cint* arr){  // pointer to const int
    //arr[0] = 42; //This will fail
    arr = nullptr;
}

template<class T>
struct Types {
    using Tptr = T*;
    using ConstT = const T;
};

template<class T>
T grootste(typename Types<T>::constT* arr, int length) { //pointer to const T, i.e Ts in the array cannot change
    //...
}
```